# Cannot start service TridionAccessManagement on computer

Tags: content-manager, sites-9.6

We are upgrading CM from 9.1 to 9.6. We are followed SDL Documents to install Sites 9.6 .exe and installed success fully. Earlier we are used SAML authentication to connect CMS. In this Upgrade process we are skipped Acess Management.

later we realised, SAML Authentication deprecated in sites 9.6. So, we have followed below link to installing the Access Management.
https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2020/12/03/installation-of-access-management-in-sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/

while installing the service, we are getting below error and Unable to start the service. can you please help us, how to resolve this one.

We have created Self-signed Certificate Using Code mentioned in above link and install the Certificate. Once we installed we did not find this certificate in User/Computer certificates. but .pfx file avaiable in respective 'bin/certificates' Path. is it expected?

We have provided required full access to "Key" folder & Changed Evnironment value to "Development" in Install Service.ps1 & start.ps1.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating the self-signed certificate file using the script, yes. It's expected it will create the file in **bin/certificates**.

Try following steps to troubleshoot.

1. Ensure DotNetCore windows hosting (3.1.20) prerequisites are installed correctly. sometimes I noticed first-time install did not work. I did re-install fixed the issue.
2. Try enabling **appsettings.json** Debug logs to see if there are any errors.

```
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Error"
    },
```

3. Make sure the port which you trying to run it's not used by other services.

I'm not sure your manual steps are correct or not. you can also try the access management installation using this [PowerShell script](https://github.com/avmgan/AccessManagementInstallationScript).

Comment: Thanks @velmurugan, if i installed laters version of DotNetCore its' installed successfully. but if i browse the URL, it's getting this error "One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, ))
Check the logs for more information." Is it required to install react.js? or its related to other issue?

Comment: @Chandana Good to know installation works. then it could be due to your browser blocking the JavaScript. not required to install npm. maybe try to access the application outside in the chrome browser. if that answer helped you to fix the issue, please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: no blocking JS on Browser, i have verified settings & tried in other browsers as well but no luck. if i hit "http://localhost:82/" its redirecting to "http://localhost:82/access-management/ui/" and showing error. On installation service is installed, but no sites creation on IIS. is it expected?

Comment: If you installed it as a windows service. then yes IIS won't create anything. it's a DotNetCore rest application.

Comment: Is there any Sample JSON or script for Create SAML Provider? @velmurugan

Comment: that script will also work for SAML IDP provider JSON install. you can raise a separate question for the sample SAML JSON idp provider.

Comment: @Ajay - If the answer helped to resolve your issue upvote and accept this answer to close.

Comment: Are you accessing AM over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

> We have provided required full access to "Key" folder & Changed Evnironment value to "Development" in Install Service.ps1 & start.ps1.

I wouldn't use "Development" in the installScript.ps1 as this is used to tell ASPNET Core about the runtime environment (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments).

I suspect by using "Development" this is triggering some internal logic within the AccessManagement app to set-up React middleware, e.g. UseReactDevelopmentServer - similar to what's shown here https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2019/11/13/how-does-the-aspnetcore-spa-development-experience-work.html. Hence your error about the "create-react-app server".

Reinstall but don't pass an Environment variable so it uses the default (Production).